# Gmail filters exclude group of words

Tags: gmail-filters

I want to filter emails by their subject. The subject should contain one phrase, but exclude words that I specified.

For example it should put all email messages with the subject `USB 3.0` in a folder, but **not** with subjects like `Notebook with USB 3.0` or `USB 3.0 Hub`.

So I tried to create a filter with the following in the subject box:

`"USB 3.0" -(Notebook OR 2,5" OR Seagate OR RAID OR HDD OR TB OR Hub OR Bus OR WD OR "Western Digital")`

My try isn't working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Gmail filters will work with parentheses like that. I think you'll need to negate every term.

```
subject:"USB 3.0" -Notebook -"2,5" -Seagate -RAID -HDD -TB -Hub -Bus -WD -"Western Digital"
```

All that said, filters are generally just saved searches, so try searching for `"USB 3.0" -Notebook` and keep adding terms until you get back the results you want, then save it as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get your search right by means of the regular Gmail filtering functionality, you have the option of using IMAP: Get all your email into a client (such as [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters)) which features its own set of advanced filtering methods.

If you have really advanced filtering needs, you can resort to exporting your messages to a repository of local `.eml` files. You can search these using any program of choice, e.g., Emacs. I recommend Google Takeout and [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/).

These methods won't let you use Gmail filter functionality such as labeling messages, but at least you'll be able to locate the correct subset of messages.